# Error with C# and SQL Server database with LinqToSql System.Data.Linq.DuplicateKeyException: Unable to add an entity with a key already in use.'

Tags: c#, sql-server, database, visual-studio, linq-to-sql

I created six tables, named `stagiaire` and `utilisateur`, in SQL Server. Initially, I set the primary key in each table to be the ID. Running the code above immediately returned this output:

```
Create Database gestionStagiaire
use gestionStagiaire

if OBJECT_ID('tempdb..ville') is not null
 drop table ville
create table ville
(
    id_ville int primary key,/*identity(1,1)*/
    nom_ville varchar(50)
)

if OBJECT_ID('tempdb..stagiaire') is not null
 drop table stagiaire
create table stagiaire
(
    id_stagiaire int primary key identity(1,1),
    nom_stagiaire varchar(50),
    dateNaiss_stagiaire date,
    cin_stagiaire varchar(10),
    telephone_stagiaire varchar(15),
    email_stagiaire varchar(50),
    adresse_stagiaire varchar(100),
    id_ville int foreign key references ville(id_ville)
)



if OBJECT_ID('tempdb..ecole') is not null
 drop table ecole
create table ecole
(
    id_ecole int primary key identity(1,1),
    nom_ecole varchar(50),
    id_ville int foreign key references ville(id_ville)
)

if OBJECT_ID('tempdb..encadrant') is not null
 drop table encadrant
create table encadrant
(
    id_encadrant int primary key identity(1,1),
    nom_encadrant varchar(50)
)

if OBJECT_ID('tempdb..stage') is not null
 drop table stage
create table stage
(
    id_stage int primary key identity(1,1),
    sujet_stage varchar(100),
    dateDebut_stage date,
    dateFin_stage date,
    id_ecole int foreign key references ecole(id_ecole),
    id_stagiaire int foreign key references stagiaire(id_stagiaire),
    id_encadrant int foreign key references encadrant(id_encadrant)
)

if OBJECT_ID('tempdb..utilisateur') is not null
 drop table utilisateur
create table utilisateur
 (
    login_utilisateur varchar(50) primary key,
    nom_utilisateur varchar(50),
    pass_utilisateur varchar(50)
 )
```

C# code:

```
private void Button_AStagiaireDgv_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
        
        //DataClasses1DataContext dc = new DataClasses1DataContext(con);
        //stagiaire newStagiaire = new stagiaire();
        //newStagiaire.id_stagiaire=""
        stagiaire sr = new stagiaire();
        //sr.id_stagiaire = Convert.ToInt32(TextBox_IdStagiaire.Text);
        sr.nom_stagiaire = TextBox_NomStagiaire.Text;
        sr.dateNaiss_stagiaire = DateTime.Parse(DateTimePickerStagiaire.Text);
        sr.ci_stagiaire = TextBox_CinStagiaire.Text;
        sr.telephone_stagiaire = TextBox_TeleStagiaire.Text;
        sr.email_stagiaire = TextBox_EmailStagiaire.Text;
        sr.adresse_stagiaire = TextBox_AdresseStagiaire.Text;
        //sr.id_ville = int.Parse(TextBox_IdVilleStagiaire.Text);
        sr.id_ville = int.Parse(ComboBox_IdVilleStagiaire.Text);//.SelectedValue.ToString()
        dc.stagiaire.InsertOnSubmit(sr);
        dc.SubmitChanges();
        charge_load();
        

        /*
        //int idstagiaire = int.Parse(TextBox_IdStagiaire.Text);
        string nomstagiaire = TextBox_NomStagiaire.Text;
        DateTime datenaiss = DateTime.Parse(DateTimePickerStagiaire.Text);
        string cinstagiaire = TextBox_CinStagiaire.Text;
        string telstagiaire = TextBox_TeleStagiaire.Text;
        string mailstagiaire = TextBox_EmailStagiaire.Text;
        string adressestagiaire = TextBox_AdresseStagiaire.Text;
        int idville = int.Parse(ComboBox_IdVilleStagiaire.Text);

        var st = new stagiaire
        {
            //id_stagiaire = idstagiaire,
            nom_stagiaire = nomstagiaire,
            dateNaiss_stagiaire = datenaiss,
            ci_stagiaire = cinstagiaire,
            telephone_stagiaire = telstagiaire,
            email_stagiaire = mailstagiaire,
            adresse_stagiaire = adressestagiaire,
            id_ville = idville
        };
        dc.stagiaire.InsertOnSubmit(st);
        dc.SubmitChanges();
        MessageBox.Show("Ajoute avec succes");
        charge_load();
        */
    }
```

Comment: *"Running the code above immediately returned this output"* What code? What output? What is your question?

Comment: Why, in your SQL, are you checking if an object exists in `tempdb`, but then creating the object in the database you just created (`gestionStagiaire`)? What's the point in checking if the object exists when it won't stop the following statement failing; not that it will as you just created the database.

Answer (score 0):

```
Create Database gestionStagiaire
use gestionStagiaire

if OBJECT_ID('tempdb..ville') is not null
 drop table ville
create table ville
(
    id_ville int primary key,/*identity(1,1)*/
    nom_ville varchar(50)
)

if OBJECT_ID('tempdb..stagiaire') is not null
 drop table stagiaire
create table stagiaire
(
    id_stagiaire int primary key identity(1,1),
    nom_stagiaire varchar(50),
    dateNaiss_stagiaire date,
    cin_stagiaire varchar(10),
    telephone_stagiaire varchar(15),
    email_stagiaire varchar(50),
    adresse_stagiaire varchar(100),
    id_ville int foreign key references ville(id_ville)
)



if OBJECT_ID('tempdb..ecole') is not null
 drop table ecole
create table ecole
(
    id_ecole int primary key identity(1,1),
    nom_ecole varchar(50),
    id_ville int foreign key references ville(id_ville)
)

if OBJECT_ID('tempdb..encadrant') is not null
 drop table encadrant
create table encadrant
(
    id_encadrant int primary key identity(1,1),
    nom_encadrant varchar(50)
)

if OBJECT_ID('tempdb..stage') is not null
 drop table stage
create table stage
(
    id_stage int primary key identity(1,1),
    sujet_stage varchar(100),
    dateDebut_stage date,
    dateFin_stage date,
    id_ecole int foreign key references ecole(id_ecole),
    id_stagiaire int foreign key references stagiaire(id_stagiaire),
    id_encadrant int foreign key references encadrant(id_encadrant)
)

if OBJECT_ID('tempdb..utilisateur') is not null
 drop table utilisateur
create table utilisateur
 (
    login_utilisateur varchar(50) primary key,
    nom_utilisateur varchar(50),
    pass_utilisateur varchar(50)
 )
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow: if you post code, XML or data samples, ***please*** highlight those lines in the text editor and click on the "code samples" button ( `{  }` ) on the editor toolbar to nicely format and syntax highlight it!